# Is it best practice to set a child element's height or the parent element's height?

Tags: css

Is it best practice to set a parent element's height and adjust all child element's based on the parent element? For example

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
.childOne {
    height: 50%;
}
.childTwo {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Or, since the parent element automatically adjusts to be the same height as the largest child element, is it best practice to set the child element sizes and allow the parent element to adjust accordingly? For example

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
}
.childOne {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.childTwo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: That depends on the situation.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: It depends on whether you want the height of the parent to be dynamic, or the height of the child to be dynamic. For a static site, you could pick either one.

Comment: @4castle say I want both to be dynamic.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that would mean. Do you want a child of the child to determine the height?

Comment: No. The parent and child elements to be dynamic.